# How can I tell if my Macbook Pro has had its SSD replaced or not?

Tags: hardware, ssd, repair

I was having issues with my work laptop so I gave it to our IT guy who sent it to Apple for repairs. When it came back he told me they had to replace the logic board (which made sense based on the problems I was having) and also the SSD (which surprised me because when I was trying to figure out what was wrong it seemed okay).

The more I think about it the more I doubt that the drive needed to be replaced. Is there any way to tell if a drive has been replaced?

My laptop is a MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Late 2013). The SSD it currently has is: **APPLE SSD SM0512G**.

Comment: I said hard drive, but I mean SSD. It had an SSD and the SSD was supposedly replaced. The laptop is a MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Late 2013).  The SSD it currently has is model APPLE SSD SM0512G

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you happened to have written down your hard drives serial number before handing it in for repairs, you could detect replacement by comparing the serial numbers.

You probably haven't written down the serial number. Then you could try looking at the drive physically to determine the production year, if written on it. If that is newer than the year your MacBook Pro was bought - it has been replaced.

You do not mention which model of MacBook Pro you have, but it must be one of the older models to have a hard drive. It could be possible to check if the disk you have is not one of the models that Apple installed from factory on your specific MacBook Pro model.

Also you could consider asking your IT guy how he knows the hard drive was replaced. Perhaps he has paper work to document it.

Comment: I should have been more accurate in my description.
The laptop is laptop is a **MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Late 2013)**
The drive it currently has is model **APPLE SSD SM0512G**

Comment: That seems to indicate that it was replaced. As far as I know, the 2013 model originally came with the SM0512F SSD. The SM0512G is a newer part.